# how can i create bunch folder with name like number-number using shell in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to create some folders in Linux using shell.

The folder names should be like this:

```
1-10000
10001-20000
20001-30000
30001-40000
```

and so on.

Which commands I should use for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir 1-10000
for i in {1..5}
do
   mkdir ${i}001-$(($i+1))000
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
for i in $(seq 0 10000 100000)
do
    mkdir $(expr $i + 1)-$(expr $i + 10000) 
done
```

The following was a suggested improvement from an anonymous user. I've added it as a separate paragraph (without verification) so that both the versions are archived.

```
for i in $(seq 0 10000 100000)
do 
     mkdir $((i + 1))-$((i + 10000))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in zsh and should also works in bash:

```
min=1; max=0; while ((max<40000)); do
  max=$((min-1+10000));
  mkdir $min-$max;
  min=$((max+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1 # Your starting number
mx=40000 # Your max number
inc=10000 # The number of entries you want in each group

while [ $n -lt $mx ]; do
  mkdir ${n}'-'$[$n+$inc-1]
  n=$[$n+$inc]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

see `man mkdir`

it should be used for creating  directory in unix.
I believe this is homework and also you havent posted anything that you have tried so far.

If you looking for a shell script then try to take the line that you have mentioned  as input and loop around the comma separated values and then split the value inside another loop and then compare with the max value after splitting and then create the directory using mkdir.algorithm goes like this:

```
for each 1-10000,10001-20000,20001-30000,30001-40000 
split value1-value2 into value1 and value2
for i=value1 and i <=value2
mkdir $i
```

Comment: I think the gist of the problem is generating that series of numbers. Not the command to create a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `zsh` alternative using the new `{start..end..step}` sequence generator:

```zsh
start=1
end=40000
step=10000
paste <(print -l {$start..$end..$step})                 \
      <(print -l {$((start + $step - 1))..$end..$step}) \
| while read n1 n2; do 
    mkdir $n1-$n2
  done
```